# How do I select an Object based on the key value - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, v-for

I have an object in Vuejs (see below). I want to select the email value ie: "foo@bar.com".

```
{
      "fields": [
        {
          "label": "email",
          "value": "foo@bar.com", 
        },
        {
          "label": "firstName",
          "value": "Foo", 
        },
        {
          "label": "lastName",
          "value": "Bar", 
        },
      ]
     }
```

I can do a

```
v-for(field in fields)
```

Then add an if statement to show only the email

```
<div v-if="field.label == 'email'">{{field.value}}</div>
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way to select the field based on a key's value without having to loop through the entire data object.

I tried unsuccessfully doing things like this:

```
fields(label, 'email')
// and
v-if fields.label == 'email'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a computed map of field `label` to `value`

```js
computed: {
  fieldMap () {
    return Object.fromEntries(this.fields.map(({ label, value }) => [ label, value ]))
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```html
<div>{{ fieldMap.email }}</div>
```

---

If you're only wanting to work with this specific field, you can create a computed property to make access easier

```js
computed: {
  emailField () {
    let field = this.fields.find(({ label }) => label === 'email')
    return field ? field.value : ''
  }
}
```

and then you can just use

```html
<div>{{ emailField }}</div>
```

Comment: Sweet, looks good to me, works a charm. Thanks for the quick reply @Phil

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively check if the current key being rendered has an index that matches the respective key with the 'email' label's own index.

Note that this will only work in this instance as we already know the exact values of the object.

```html
<div v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
  <div v-if="index === 0">
    {{ field.value }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Not email: {{ field.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would work but I don't always know the index of email.